# Google-guava checkNotNull and IntelliJ IDEA's "may produce java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: intellij-idea, nullpointerexception, guava, inspection

Is there any way to suppress this warning:

```java
MyClass object = null;

/*Some code that 'might' set this object but I know it will*/      


Preconditions.checkNotNull(object); 
//when "assert object != null" is used here no warning is shown

merged.setName(dRElement.getName());
//"May produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'" warning here
```

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 10.5 and I know this warning is unnecessary however I would like to suppress it just here and avoid switching inspections off.

Comment: Did you mean object instead of merged?

Comment: I meant object instead of 'dRElement' but in this example it's the same.

Comment: Interested too. I'm frustrated each time I have to solve this warning by duplicate assertion/suppression.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Through a combination of `@Contract` annotations and the External Annotations feature, you can now annotate `Preconditions` methods such that IntelliJ applies the correct static analysis to calls to these methods.

Let's say we have this example

```java
public void doSomething(Object someArg) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(someArg != null);
    someArg.doSomethingElse();  //currently gives NPE warning

    if (someArg != null) {
        //no warning that this is always true
    }
}
```

In IntelliJ (I'm using 13):

- Navigate to `Preconditions.checkArgument(boolean)`.
- Place your cursor on the method name, and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to bring up the intentions popup.
- Select "Add method contract".
- Use the contract text `false -> fail`.
- When prompted, provide a location for the External Annotations file.

Now the warning at `someArg.doSomethingElse()` goes away, and IDEA will, in fact, flag the `if` branch as always true!

Other contract texts:

- `Preconditions.checkArgument(boolean, String)` should be `false, _ -> fail`
- `Preconditions.checkNotNull(Object, String)` should be `null, _ -> fail`,
- etc, etc

Here is my full `annotations.xml` file for `Preconditions`:

```xml
<root>
    <item name='com.google.common.base.Preconditions T checkNotNull(T)'>
        <annotation name='org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract'>
            <val val="&quot;null -&gt; fail&quot;"/>
        </annotation>
    </item>
    <item name='com.google.common.base.Preconditions T checkNotNull(T, java.lang.Object)'>
        <annotation name='org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract'>
            <val val="&quot;null, _ -&gt; fail&quot;"/>
        </annotation>
    </item>
    <item name='com.google.common.base.Preconditions T checkNotNull(T, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)'>
        <annotation name='org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract'>
            <val val="&quot;null, _, _ -&gt; fail&quot;"/>
        </annotation>
    </item>
    <item name='com.google.common.base.Preconditions void checkArgument(boolean)'>
        <annotation name='org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract'>
            <val val="&quot;false -&gt; fail&quot;"/>
        </annotation>
    </item>
    <item name='com.google.common.base.Preconditions void checkArgument(boolean, java.lang.Object)'>
        <annotation name='org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract'>
            <val val="&quot;false, _ -&gt; fail&quot;"/>
        </annotation>
    </item>
    <item name='com.google.common.base.Preconditions void checkArgument(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)'>
        <annotation name='org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract'>
            <val val="&quot;false, _, _ -&gt; fail&quot;"/>
        </annotation>
    </item>
    <item name='com.google.common.base.Preconditions void checkState(boolean)'>
        <annotation name='org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract'>
            <val val="&quot;false -&gt; fail&quot;"/>
        </annotation>
    </item>
    <item name='com.google.common.base.Preconditions void checkState(boolean, java.lang.Object)'>
        <annotation name='org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract'>
            <val val="&quot;false, _ -&gt; fail&quot;"/>
        </annotation>
    </item>
    <item name='com.google.common.base.Preconditions void checkState(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)'>
        <annotation name='org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract'>
            <val val="&quot;false, _, _ -&gt; fail&quot;"/>
        </annotation>
    </item>
</root>
```

### See Also

- [IDEA-113391: Edit Method Contract intention for library methods](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113391)
- [IDEA-93372: Implement something similar to ReSharper contract annotations for Java](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93372)
- [IDEA-60343: False positive NPE warning when using guava Preconditions - Constant conditions & Expectations](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-60343)

Comment: Changed the answer for this. It is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: How do you setup IntelliJ to actually use that annotations.xml file?

Comment: @PeterŠtibraný: IIRC, the first time you declare an external annotation, you will be prompted for a location to create the external annotations file.  Then you can copy these contents into it.

Answer (score 15):

An [old issue exists in JetBrains Yourtrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-35808?query=%22Constant+Conditions+%26+Exceptions%22+NULL) to add this type of functionality.  I voted for it years ago, but I don't see an activity.  If everyone votes for it, then we might get lucky.

To clarify the issue covers adding functionality so that you could tag a method as performing some type of null check.  If that happened then you could write your own wrapper for the Preconditions method and annotate it.

**UPDATE**
I got tired of waiting for the functionality so I submitted a patch myself.  It is available in 12.1.1 build 129.239.  To access the configuration: Settings > Inspections > Probable Bugs > Constant Conditions & Exceptions > Configure Assert/Check Methods.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know.  I've never really seen a pattern, I think it has to do with how easily they can implement it and how strongly they like the idea.

Comment: If anyone is interested, I just submitted a patch that will hopefully add the desired functionality to Intellij.  I have no idea how long it will take for JetBrains to review the change and include it in a production release.  If you have time, please vote/comment on the issue to increase it's visibility with the JetBrains staff.  This is my first patch for Intellij, so I'm afraid it could take a long time for it to be reviewed.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution was much better than what they've implemented now. I'm really starting to regret having updated to IDEA 13 :-(

Comment: Is this gone from Idea 13? I remember setting this in previous version, but I cannot find it now.

Answer (score 2):

Extract a method?

```
private MyClass getMyClass() {
    /* This always returns an instance of MyClass, never null. */      
}

...

MyClass object = getMyClass();
Preconditions.checkNotNull(object);
merged.setName(object.getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also assign returned value from checkNotNull method, which is non-null: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkNotNull(T)

```
MyClass object = null;
object = Preconditions.checkNotNull(object); 
merged.setName(dRElement.getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

From IntelliJ IDEA 14, you don't need to worry about this.

```
@Nullable
String extractPrefix(@Nullable String url) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(url)) return null;

    if (url.startsWith("jar://")) {
...
```

> Earlier IntelliJ IDEA had no clue that code execution wouldn’t even reach the “startsWith” call if the url is null because it didn’t look inside StringUtils.isEmpty. You could of course remove those yellow warnings in extractPrefix by looking inside isEmpty yourself and adding a contract “null -> true”, but that’s so boring! That’s exactly a job for computer, not you, and now IntelliJ IDEA does it automatically, looking at byte and source code.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/10/automatic-notnullnullablecontract-inference-in-intellij-idea-14/

Answer (score 0):

Apart from other options, you can try-

Suppress warnings at method level by using -

```
@SuppressWarnings({"NullableProblems"})
public void someMethod(){
   ...
   ...
}
```

or suppress warning at statement level by using comment -

```
//noinspection NullableProblems
someMethodCallProducingNullWarning(null);
```

But before doing this - make sure that it doesn't really produce NPE

Comment: These are default options. You can `assert var != null` together with `Preconditions.checkNotNull` but it is redundant just like `//noinspection`.

Comment: here is the code [link](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=t6UxaA2p), the tabs are messed a bit due to copy paste